# SQL Select sum count multiple times with seperate where values

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to pull the count of the same column three times using different "where" values.
for instance

```
SELECT (sum(count(phonenum) FROM table1 WHERE uniqueID IN ( 123, 43, 124, 44, 112)) AS blabla_LTD)
    ,(sum(count(phonenum) FROM table1 WHERE uniqueID IN (163, 53, 114, 45, 222)) AS lablab_LTD)
```

Expected

```
Blabla_LTD  LABLAB_LTD
1234         11234
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the subqueries, but I think conditional aggregation may be more efficient:

```
select sum(case when uniqueID IN ( 123, 43, 124, 44, 112)
                then 1 else 0
           end) AS blabla_LTD,
       sum(case when uniqueID IN (163, 53, 114, 45, 222)
                then 1 else 0
           end) AS lablab_LTD
from table1 
where phonenum is not null;
```

If you have an index on `uniqueId`, then including all the `ids` in a `where` clause may also help performance:

```
where uniqueId in (123, 43, 124, 44, 112, 163, 53, 114, 45, 222)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it for you:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN uniqueID IN ( 123, 43, 124, 44, 112) AND phoneNum IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    , SUM(CASE WHEN uniqueID IN (163, 53, 114, 45, 222) AND phoneNum IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table1
```